# SQL query with two different ids

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sql-update, subquery

I need to prevent `photo_order` field from exceeding number of photos being associated with article. I have this, but it doesn't work. Table name has been used two times and it is probably wrong.

```
UPDATE articles_photos SET photo_order = 
    IF(photo_order < (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM articles_photos
        WHERE article_id = 12), photo_order + 1, 1) WHERE id = 26
```

How can I fix above query? My database is MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is the error you are getting:

> You can't specify target table 'articles_photos' for update in FROM
>   clause

Here's one work around using a `cross join` with a subquery:

```
update articles_photos ap
cross join (select count(id) cnt from articles_photos where article_id = 12) temp
set ap.photo_order = if(ap.photo_order<temp.cnt,ap.photo_order+1,1)
where ap.id = 26;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37ffb4/1)